how can I save the code for a function into a file from within an R program
I'm using the Deriv package, which generates new functions, and I want to store that code into a file, from within an R program.
So I define a function:
f=function(x){x^2}

And I calculate the derivative:
fd=Deriv(f,"x")

fd is now a new function.
On the console I can type "fd", and that will show me the code for the new function.
On the console, I can then use the following 3 commands to save that function into a file, for future use:
sink("myr.R")
fd
sink()

Now, I want to run all those commands from within an R program.
It seems to me that I want to convert the output from Deriv into a string, but I don't know how to do that.

Is there a reason why you need to save the computed function, rather than re-computing it using Deriv? In general we distinguish between the source code and computed results, and we don’t save computed results as code (if anything we cache them in a machine-readable format such as RDS, but even that requires care to ensure reproducibility).

Storing only the code of a function is a dangerous practice. The text is only part of an R function. The rest of it is stored in its associated environment.

Notwithstanding the previous comments, you might find formals(your_function) and body(your_function) useful on some occasions.

Thx for the comments and suggestions. I'm making a library that calculates derivs of complex functions 1000s of times, and I'm trying to write code for that. I started working out the derivatives using pencil and paper and coding them in by hand. But that was killing me. Then I found this Deriv function, which seems to be a way to write the code I need. I'd rather derive the code once and for all and then hard-wire it, rather than at run-time, to make my library go faster. I've tested it, and it's all working a treat.  But let me know if there's something problematic about that.

Basically, I'm using Deriv instead of mathematica to derive the equations I need.

Btw, here's a better justification for saving the auto-generated code from Deriv() in a file. One of the derivatives I'm calculating is the 3rd derivative tensor of a 6 parameter statistical model. It takes Deriv() about 6 minutes to calculate the derivative and write the code (!). To actually run the code once it's been generated takes a fraction of a second.

I think I've answered my own question, using:
sink("myr.R")
print.function(fd)
sink()


I don’t think that is any different than your first three lines of code. You have only made explicit the print component of the parse-eval-print loop of the console.

I can't find the unsink command, but the sink documentation seems to suggest just saying sink() to unsink, and that seems to work.

Ha. You’re exactly right. I’m deleting the evidence. :-) But now you need to consider using save/load or making a package.
